# How to make a tab bar that shows colored icons , on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, button, uitabbar

I need to make a toolbar on the bottom of the screen with some buttons. I want in every button to have a small image and a small text under it. The closest i can find from "Xcode" is the "Tab Bar" where you can put icons and text but the problem is that when you add an image you can only see the shadow of the image and not its colors.. Can i change that? Or is another way to make a toolbar like the one i am describing?

### EDIT

I need the buttons to change controllers and i just noticed that i cant create actions for the tabs but only outlets. So i guess the tab bar is not what i should use. Any ideas for a toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Tab Bar is the Best approach for it and it is very easy to customize the tab bar if u are using IO5

This [LINK](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html) will be helpful.

There is another approach (which was applicable uptil IOS4 for customization of Tab bar) was to Create Custom buttons with tab bar look alike Images. it will give u the same feel, but like i said it is very easy now to customize IOS Tab bars

Here is a couple of Links for u

[LINK 1](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboards_to_create_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Tab_Bar_Application) With Story BOARD

[LINK 2](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Multiview_Application_using_the_Tab_Bar) Without Storyboard

One More thing Try searching Google before Posting a question here if have some problem then feel free to post along with the code or tutorial u tried.

Let me know if i Worked

Cheers

W

Comment: Ok this does show colored icons BUT it doesnt show how to put text under every icon.

Comment: see link 2 it tells u how to create a Tab bar. First Create a Tab bar then customize it